# How to display info from an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

If my array states:

```
[mostPlayedGames] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [gameName] => Counter-Strike: Global Offensive [gameLink] => http://steamcommunity.com/app/730 [gameIcon] => http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/730/69f7ebe2735c366c65c0b33dae00e12dc40edbe4.jpg [gameLogo] => http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/730/d0595ff02f5c79fd19b06f4d6165c3fda2372820.jpg [gameLogoSmall] => http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/730/d0595ff02f5c79fd19b06f4d6165c3fda2372820_thumb.jpg [hoursPlayed] => 28.0 [hoursOnRecord] => 527 [statsName] => CSGO ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [gameName] => Borderlands: The Pre-Sequel [gameLink] => http://steamcommunity.com/app/261640 [gameIcon] => http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/261640/af5ef05eac8b1eb618e4f57354ac7b3e918ab1bd.jpg [gameLogo] => http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/261640/df64c72fd335a03dbcc0a19b1f81acc8db1b94ba.jpg [gameLogoSmall] => http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/261640/df64c72fd335a03dbcc0a19b1f81acc8db1b94ba_thumb.jpg [hoursPlayed] => 10.9 [hoursOnRecord] => 10.9 [statsName] => 261640 )
```

and I want to display info from the first part of the array( 0 ), how would I go about doing that if I was using code like this to display it:

```
echo "CS:GO Hours Played: {$user->mostPlayedGames???}, PHP_EOL;
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `{$user->mostPlayedGames[0]->hoursOnRecord}`

Answer (score 0):

Your `mostPlayedGames` array doesn't seem like it is an `stdClass` of any variable named `$user`, so let's not over complicate it.

```
$mostPlayedGames = [mostPlayedGames] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [gameName]....[snippet]
```

Now that we have that clear:

```
echo "CS:GO Hours Played: ${mostPlayedGames[0]->hoursPlayed}".PHP_EOL;
```

You see, The first element in this is an `array` at position `0` so we must first move to that index position. The element at index `0` is an `stdClass` so then we can use the accessor method `->` to grab properties of this object.

Comment: Sorry I left out majority of the code I was working with. Adding the 0 fixed the problem I was having. Thank you for your help.